# Better way to change data format inside JSON (Regex ?!)

Tags: javascript, json, regex, date, datetime

My CRM send the following JSON to my webhook:

```
"last_conversion":
            {
                "content":
                {
                    "identifier":"conv-list",
                    "created_at":"2020-05-09T22:06:29.049670Z",
                    "Name":"Test",
                    "BusinessName":"Test Business",
                    "Phone":"+201 (99) 9999-9999",
                    "gclid_field":"232938293"
                },
                "created_at":"2020-05-09T19:06:29.049-05:00"
}
```

Sending information to google ads requires a specific data format:

[image: Google accepted formats]

I would like to create a json with the following format:

```
{
"content_created_at":"2020-05-09T22:06:29-05:00",
"Name":"Test",
"created_at": "2020-05-09T19:06:29-05:00"
}
```

To achieve that, i should change both created_at keys

1) 2020-05-09T22:06:29.049670Z
to 
2020-05-09T22:06:29-05:00 (Removing the **.049670Z** and adding **-05:00**)

2) 2020-05-09T19:06:29.049-05:00
to 
2020-05-09T19:06:29-05:00 (Removing the **.049**)

What is the most elegant way to achieve that? I'm trying some kind of regex but is not working as intended

Comment: You can't use a regular expression to add the offset because a regular expression doesn't know what it is, or how to adjust the date and time values. You can convert the string to a Date and format it as required, there are many, many questions here already on formatting dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use regex here. 
Just convert the date string into a JS Date object:

```
const date = new Date("2020-05-09T22:06:29.049670Z")
```

Once you did this you can use the [date methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to format your data.

For a more pleasant experience when working with dates in JS, you could also take a look at [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/).